# UIBarButtonItem not display on UITableViewcontroller

Tags: swift, uitableview, navigation, uibarbuttonitem, invisible

I have a UITableViewcontroller embedded in a navigation controller.  I added a UIBarButtonItem and set the layout guide so the button is viewable.  I created a button ("Next") to allow me to navigate to the next screen.  The Next button never appears.  Is it hiding behind the TableViewCells?

Thanks,

Comment: could you upload an screenshot of your UITableViewcontroller with the left panel (hierarchy UI)

Comment: ![Heirarhcy](http://i.imgur.com/WDlYtmZ.png).
![View controller](http://i.imgur.com/weqPou8.png).

Comment: @SantosRamón i uploaded the pics.  you have to click the hyperlink to access.  i dont know how to display them by default.

Comment: An alternate solution is to create a UIViewController and put a UITableView in the UIViewcontroller.